# Who are we quoting when we note that "Code is written once but read many times"?

Tags: history

I have often heard or read the expression, "**code is written once but read many times**". I think this is a fairly well-known principle of software development. But I have no idea with whom to credit with the notion.

Its not hard to find references which use it, but I don't think I've ever seen a citation or credit given. It could be someone well known (e.g., Donald Knuth? Douglas Hofstadter? "Gang of Four"?) or less well known but *deserving recognition* for the insight.

Examples of usage:

> *Code is read much more often than it is written*, so plan accordingly...

([Raymond Chen article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070406-00/?p=27343) )

> ...the ratio of *time spent reading versus writing* is well over 10 to 1.
> We are constantly reading old code as part of the effort to write new code.

([Robert C. Martin, Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/835238-indeed-the-ratio-of-time-spent-reading-versus-writing-is))

Wording varies, but its the same idea.

I guess its possible that the original statement of this idea predates computer programming. Artifacts such as cooking recipes, circuit diagrams, architectural plans, etc. probably share the same principle. But still, someone had to eventually recognize the application to source code and write about it or otherwise popularize the idea.

Comment: In example 1 it is not used as a quote from someone else, it is just a statement of a fact. In the second example the source of the quote is given.

Comment: @UncleBod the second is a list of quotes from a certain book, and this happened to be one of them. Its not presented as the origination of the saying.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to know *how* the 10:1 ratio was determined.

Comment: Regarding the close votes - does this not fall under "computing history and persons with a historic relation to computing" which is explicitly on-topic? Or is there some other reason for the close votes? Some feedback would be welcome.

Comment: I find this an interesting question and I've posted a similar question at least once on either StackOverflow or Programmers. But it's not retro. It applies today as much as ever, it's used today as much as ever, and it isn't more applicable to old fashioned computers than modern computers. I'm looking for my old question to link to before I recommend which SE site to move this to...

Comment: I would agree that the question area _is_ in general on-topic for RC.SE. But at the same time it specific is unfit by asking for something that can't have a definite Answer, as the quotation is simply a statement of fact that for sure has been made a zillion times in various circumstances.

Comment: I said this in 1971 and I was not quoting anyone.

Comment: I can't find my old question unfortunately. I would probably post in SE's main Meta site asking where to ask. I disagree that such questions can't have definite answers. We do in fact know the exact origin of many quotations and even many words and phrases. It's like the halting problem. Not knowing whether you'll find the answer is not the same as knowing there is no answer. But indeed some are in fact just commonplace observations. You could try asking on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/). I've been lucky there before.

Comment: Given that it's a current computer science principle, _Computer Science_ stack exchange might be worth considering.

Comment: @Raffzahn I don't see how one can find out if there is or is not a definite answer unless you ask the question first :)   This is the kind of thing that might just be "folk" wisdom. On the other hand there could still be "seminal" writings which at least popularized the idea, if not originated it.

Comment: @hippietrail thanks for looking, I'll post on meta and see what people think. I'm not too familiar with the CS site myself.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs The question is much like asking who first stated that the sky is blue. Doesn't need much knowledge to see that it's fruitless.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs: I hunted through a couple of SEs for a few hours and the reception of such questions doesn't match my recollection. More than a couple are closed. It's come up in Meta a couple of times. It's unclear whether you're asking about an "expression" or a "notion". Somebody was first to say it in this catchy way, maybe somebody famous, maybe not. Finding who first thought something kinda sorta like it though I have to agree is not going to have an origin anyway.

Comment: Having said all that, as a quote it's been attributed to [Robert C Martin in *Clean Code*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/835238-indeed-the-ratio-of-time-spent-reading-versus-writing-is) but that book is only from 2008 which seems far too recent. The short version is probably influenced by [WORM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many), which in turn is related to ROM.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a definitive answer (I doubt anybody can--any citation is subject to others finding older citations), but the first time I heard it pointed out frequently was when Ada 83 was being designed.

Although it doesn't say it quite the same way, the [Ada 83 Language Reference Manual](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-01-03.html) (LRM) does say:

> The need for languages that promote reliability and simplify maintenance is well established. Hence emphasis was placed on program **readability over ease of writing**.

[emphasis added]

Although it's stating it slightly differently, this clearly reflects the same basic idea.

At the same time, it makes clear that this is not a new observation--that it is already "well established". As such, I'd guess there's at least a decent chance of somebody finding a still older reference to at least the same general idea, if not identical wording.

I suppose there's also room for question about exactly how close to the same something has to be to qualify as an older reference. Just for example, in the preface to *Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs*, Niklaus Wirth mentions:

> This is particularly true of the relatively involved and long examples of programs. Their inclusion in this book is not accidental. Longer programs are the "normal" case in practice, and they are much more suitable for exhibiting that elusive but essential ingredient called style and orderly structure. They are also meant to serve as exercises in the art of program *reading*, which too often is neglected in favor of program writing.

This doesn't specifically mention how much/often code is read vs. written, but clearly points toward the fact that he viewed reading code as having greater importance than it often treated as having.

---

*Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs*, Niklaus Wirth, 1976

Comment: On a side note, it was already part of the specification for [Algol58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_58) (at that time called IAL). From the 1958 Zürich conference papers : _"The syntax of the language should be as close as possible to standard mathematical notation, and programs in it should be readable with little further explanation."_ Wirth, who studied at the time in Zürich created [Algol W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_W) in 1966 so I guess the idea was there already way before Ada.